# How do you run an api call through a try/catch to ensure connection is working?

Tags: php, rest, try-catch

I have an api call that I want to run through a try/catch statement.

I have tried both ‘try/catch’ and an ‘if/else’ to check to see if the api call can be made.

When internet is disconnected both methods crash and call an error,

```
file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

1 method)

```
try {
  $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/'), true);
  $BTCprice=$json["0"]["price_usd"];
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $BTCprice = 0;
}
```

2 method)

```
if ( file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/') ) {
  $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/'), true);
  $BTCprice=$json["0"]["price_usd"];
} else {
  $BTCprice = 0;
}
```

How do you run an api call through a try/catch to ensure connection is working?

Comment: Are you sure your second method crashes with an error? I asume its a warning.

Comment: You a right, it probably is and framework is just turning it into a crash

Comment: `try/catch` is for catching exceptions, not any error.

Comment: You should probably check what `file_get_contents()` actually return before you try and use the result by passing it to `json_decode()`.

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents()` does not throw exceptions, only returning false on failure. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

So, that said, option 2 is the way to do it. However, I would tweak it, because you make the request TWICE.

```
<?php

$BTCprice = 0;
if ($data = file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/') ) {
  $json = json_decode($data, true);
  $BTCprice = $json["0"]["price_usd"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it like this

```
if($json === FALSE) { 
    $BTCprice = 0; 
} else {
   //your thing
}
```

if you want to ignore the error msg you can also use php [error control operator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)